# Convert GWT web game to support mobile browsers

Tags: android, css, iphone, mobile, gwt

I have a web game that was built in GWT. I am really struggling to make it mobile-friendly. To support multiple screen sizes for desktop, I just used the transform: scale(*) CSS property, but it doesn't seem to apply well for the mobile browsers. 
Any guidelines/tips about how to tackle this?
http://www.poker-fighter.com/PokerFighter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much GWT-specific about responsive design. Most of the techniques are the same for all HTML/CSS/JS frameworks. (NB: You should *never* use `scale()` as a way to fit into a screen size.)

What I really like about the GWT, however, is the ability to create different layouts for different screen sizes, and create separate permutations for phones and tablets/desktop instead of using media query break points or other techniques that bloat the code or CSS files.

To accomplish that, typically, I create an abstract view implementation (i.e. GameboardViewImpl) that includes code and UI references common to all form factors, and then extend this abstract view implementation to create form-factor-specific implementations, e.g. GameboardViewImplDesktop and GameboardViewImplPhone. This approach not only creates smaller and more efficient code, it creates code that is much easier to develop and maintain. You can simply refresh the browser and see how each view looks in desktop, tablet or phone form factor, and if something does not look right, you know exactly where to fix it.

Take a look at [MGWT](http://www.m-gwt.com/) - you may or may not need all the platform-specific widgets and styles it comes with, but at a minimum you can use `MGWT.getFormFactor()` and similar methods.

Comment: Thanks. 1. Why shouldn't I use scale? 2. I actually almost didn't use any widget, so I don't think MGWT can help me. Layout wise, let's say I just want the most trivial thing - have the exact same layout but I want it to fit into a mobile screen. Still don't understand how can I accomplish that.

Comment: There are many reasons not to use scale, but the most important: it can make the UI unreadable or absurdly large when you scale from my screen (2560x1440 CSS pixels) to some small phone (320x533 CSS pixels). And you do not take advantage of xhdpi and hdpi resolutions to make your game look sharp.

Comment: MGWT makes it easy to detect which form factors and screen densities your users have. You can do it in pure JS, of course, if you prefer.